# ContentPage constructor called before AppStart

Tags: xamarin.forms, initialization

I thought AppStart would be a good place to put some app initialization, particularly for `HttpClient`, so that it would execute before any app views were created.

However, in the debugger, I see that my view `ContentPage` constructor is called before AppStart.

Where should I be doing global initialization, such as this?

Comment: What do you mean by AppStart ? Have you tried to initialize in the constructor of App.cs class? before assigning `MainPage` property and before `InitializeComponent`

Comment: AppStart is a member function of Application. But, your mention of  InitializeComponent, which happens in the constructor of Application, may be the clue. I'll try moving HttpClient init to the constructor and see if that solves the problem.